# trying to POST referral URL to another php file

Tags: php, mysql

OK So I am trying to create a referral script in which if a user joins via a members referral url, then upon their details being submitted to the database, their referrer's username (if any) is also submitted to the column 'referedby' Now the following code seemed to get the previous URL until I tried to POST the referral to another php file.

I have `index.php` which simply loads various `iframes`. So when users come to my site the page they actually see is home.php. I put this code in index.php. When a user enters their details and goes to the next page, shop.php the code returns nothing into 'referredby' column.

The code did work as in it return domainname/home.php into 'referredby' when the code was in home.php. So I made it so the referral was passed from `index.php` to `home.php` to use but it always returned blank.

Thank you in advance, I am pretty new to PHP so forgive me is it's blatantly obvious. Which quite often seems to be the case after hours of troubleshooting!

Currently In index.php, have tried putting it in `home.php` (without the POST) but returns `domainname/home.php` as 'referredby'

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) // check if referrer is set
    {

    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // set ref
    }
    else
    {
        $ref = '';
    }
     ?>



  <form action="POST" method="home.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="ref" value= $ref />
    </form>
```

In `home.php` I have this but its returning nothing into ref.

```
$run = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".MYSQLTABLE."(id, address, ip, date, time, referredby) VALUES('','" . $_POST['address'] . "','" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', '".date("Y-m-d")."', '".date("D")."', '".$_POST['ref']."')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong way to set php variable value in html field change

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref" value= $ref />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref" value="<?php echo $ref;?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I will also look into Sessions to prevent SQL injections as adreas said.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref" value= $ref />
```

into

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref" value="<?php echo $ref; ?>" />
```

But it is a bad idea to do it like this. People can just give other data and insert it in your database. (or even worse: do SQL injection)

You can lookup PHP Sessions

Answer (score -1):

Instead putting into hidden value you can store it in session so that you will find it easily

Comment: feel free to post quality answers with supporting code